# In UWP I want to get a ListView elements checkboxes's value

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, uwp-xaml

So I'm trying to do a program that uses ListView (instead of CheckedListBox), and I want to get the indexes of the checked elements.

I use this as a template for the ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="Content" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="303" Margin="10,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="394" ItemClick="Content_ItemClick" SelectionChanged="Content_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected}"></CheckBox>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And this is the data what it got:

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

How could I get back the checked elements index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your ListView's item source is bound to a backing list

```
    <ListView  ItemSource"{x:Bind UserList, Mode=OneWay}" >
    <ListItem.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
           <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay} Click="Click_Handler"/>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
         </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
     </ListItem.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

The `UserList` is `List<User>` which contains all your `User`.
Since you bind the `UserList` to the `ListView`. You could retrieve the selected item by iterating through the list and read the `Selected` property of each individual `User`.